# How to do a JOIN in MySQL with no linked lines

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, one being users and the other linked programs through a many-to-many relationship through a user_programs table.

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Jonathan |
|  2 | Little   |
|  3 | Annie    |
|  4 | Bob      |
+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from programs;
+-----+----------------------+
| id  | name                 |
+-----+----------------------+
|  10 | Microsoft Word       |
|  20 | Microsoft Excel      |
|  30 | Microsoft PowerPoint |
+-----+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from link;
+---------+------------+
| user_id | program_id |
+---------+------------+
|       1 |         20 |
|       1 |         30 |
|       2 |         20 |
|       3 |         10 |
+---------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I understand how to join the tables and return a result of this type, filtering only user programs 1 - Jonathan:

```
mysql> 
select users.name, programs.program from user_programs
     join users on users.id = user_programs.user_id
     left join programs on programs.id = user_programs.program_id
     where users.id = 1;
+----------+----------------------+
| name     | name                 |
+----------+----------------------+
| Jonathan | Microsoft Excel      |
| Jonathan | Microsoft PowerPoint |
+----------+----------------------+
```

but what I really need is to bring not only Jonathan's programs, but also programs that he doesn't have yet.

**Like this below:**

```
+----------+----------------------+
| name     | name                 |
+----------+----------------------+
| Jonathan | Microsoft Excel      |
| Jonathan | Microsoft PowerPoint |
|          | Microsoft Word       |
+----------+----------------------+
```

I got a lot of joins but I couldn't. Does anyone know how to do?
thanks

Comment: This is vague, but whatever you're asking, it's a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. [ask] Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that. PS When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join `programs` to the other tables with `left` joins:

```
select u.name, p.name program 
from programs p
left join link l on l.program_id = p.id and l.user_id = 1
left join users u on u.id = l.user_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nABGKa9bwxNn6t3EtKQ5n2/1).
Results:

```
| name     | program              |
| -------- | -------------------- |
| Jonathan | Microsoft Excel      |
| Jonathan | Microsoft PowerPoint |
|          | Microsoft Word       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need simply a group by at the end

```
SELECT 
    users.name, GROUP_CONCAT(programs.program)
FROM
    user_programs
        JOIN
    users ON users.id = user_programs.user_id
        LEFT JOIN
    programs ON programs.id = user_programs.program_id
WHERE
    users.id = 1
GROUP BY users.id ,users.name;
```

I had it wreitten differently

```
SELECT
    u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(p.program)
 FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN 
    user_programs u_p ON u.id = u_p.user_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    programs p ON p.id = u_p.program_id
GROUP BY u.id ,u.name;
```

EXAMPLE
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVvbUy1rirBp5tD9Fq9J8X/1